# Chrome Extension: Would changing content_security_policy in manifest disable past users?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, content-security-policy

I know that *changing permissions will disable your existing users*, thats why you can use optional permissions. However, `content_security_policy` adds another layer to this.

**Here is my current setup:**

My permissions:

```json
"permissions": [
    "storage"
],
```

Currently using `content_scripts`

```json
"content_scripts": [ {
        "all_frames": true,
        "js": [
            "js/helpers/BrowserStorage.js",
            "js/helpers/LocalStorage.js",
            "js/helpers/Device.js",
            "js/frame.js"
        ],
        "matches": [
            "https://example.com/*"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_start"
} ],
```

And currently using the `content_security_policy`

```json
"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src https://*.example.com 'self';  object-src 'self'"
```

This has allowed my current user base to enable access to `example.com`, without adding `example.com` into permissions in the first place. Which I feel like I should have done to begin with, nonetheless, I forgot.

**Questions
:**

1. If I were to add `example.com` into the permissions section, would that disable current users, even though my domain is already allowed from the previous 2 sections above?
2. If I were to change the `content_security_policy` with either another domain name OR add other elements using the same domain name, would permissions be disabled on existing users?

*Example*:

if I were to change it to this instead, **would existing users be disabled?**

```json
"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'sha256-tempUn1btibnrWwQxEk37lMGV1Nf8FO/GXxNhLEsPdg=' 'sha256-7KQKVSgvvLBSyYII9Tvlef97RiFP4uLjKxCP55HNxC8=' https://example.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src https://example.com 'self';  object-src 'self'; img-src https://example.com; connect-src https://example.com"
```

Thanks, hopefully someone might be able to help on understanding what might trigger permissions, I hate to disable existing users, and its almost impossible to really test this.

Answer (score 0):

Browser extensions are loaded on the user's device and store the application manifest and permissions there.

Changing permissions will NOT disable existing users until they update Extension.
After updating, the Extension should check existing permissions and re-ask permissions if it changed those's set.
Otherwice the Extension wil failed to operate properly ("*will disable your existing users*" in your words).

In case of `content_security_policy` key in the manifest file the situation is easier.
Past users still have an old Extension with an old manifest and old `content_security_policy` key value. So they will not be blocked.
After updating the Extension, users will got a new manifest with a new `content_security_policy` key value, so all should be OK.

PS: The answer is not based on my previous experience, but based only on how things should work.

Comment: All users will always update the extension, its 99% auto-updating on browser restart, so dont really care to those who dont update, they will always update. And once they do restart the browser and it updates, I want to be sure the extension doesnt disable by permission change, which will happen if the permissions are new. My thing is to check that adding the same domain thats already approved using `content_security_policy` wont trigger a required permission. This is just not clear in documentation.

Comment: "permissions" is what is required from user to allow access camera/microphone/storage/sensors/geolocation etc on device. The usage of Content Security Policy in the Extension does not require any permissions from the user. At least I do not see it among [Chrome Extension permissions](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7515036?hl=en) list.

Comment: Good point! I think changes there should be safe, the only thing I would say is, if I add another domain name to the content policy, then it would flag it since It would be needed in approval by the user since any external domain used gets added as a "origin" permission. at least from my tests, my domain was added into the users permission dialog, but its not explicitly set in permissions